# Definition of monotonicity on multivariable functions $f:\mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$

Tags: functions, vector-spaces, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, vector-analysis

I have a question about the monotonicity definition when it's applied to high-dimensional functions $f:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$.

In the answer of my other question: [Monotonicity of Convex/Concave Function's Gradient Function in High Dimension, URL (version: 2020-11-13)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3905769), user [daw](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/136544/daw) gives a definition with

$$
( f(x) -  f(y) ) ^T(x-y) \ge 0
$$
for all $x,y$.

Is this a general definition about monotonicity in $f:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$? For example, suppose $g:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a *concave* function, let $f=\nabla g:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$. I believe we have
$$
(f(x)-f(y))^T(x-y)\leq 0 \,\, \,\, \big(\text{i.e. }( \nabla g(x) - \nabla g(y) ) ^T(x-y) \le 0\big)
$$
for any *concave* function $g$ (can be proved with concavity definition $g(y)\leq g(x) + \nabla g(x)^T(y-x)$).

If so, then I am really confused. Does this mean the gradient of multi-variable *concave* function is not monotone? Or the monotonicity definition of  $( f(x) -  f(y) ) ^T(x-y) \ge 0$ on multivariable function $f:\mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ is not formal?

Comment: When you say monotone, do you mean increasing or decreasing? When compared with the 1D case, we should expect that the gradient of a concave function should be monotonically decreasing (while a convex function is increasing). This seems to be what you’ve shown.